# How can i upload multiple files in node.js?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I need help in upload multiple files using node.js upload file reader.

I am using the `fs = require('fs')`.
I have problem  in  choose two files,only one file only write in upload directory.

This is my backend

```
var files = req.files.files[0];
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {    
  file = files[i];
  fs.readFile(files[i].path, function(error, data) {
    // console.log( files[i].path ) ,here displayed two same both
    fs.writeFile(uploadDirectory() + newFileName, data, function(error) {
    });
  });
}
```

Please help me.
what is the problem in my code.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhantomJS Node - page.open - cannot keep track of multiple pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086360/phantomjs-node-page-open-cannot-keep-track-of-multiple-pages)

Comment: Where is `newFileName` being defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using `files[i]` in asynchronous function's callback which is directly written inside of for-loop.
the reason why `console.log( files[i].path )` displays same thing twice is because when the code is loaded,the for-loop has already done. so you always get the last element of the array.

the easiest way to fix that is making a new scope(function)

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {    
  readAndWriteFile(files[i]);
}

var readAndWriteFile = function(file){
    fs.readFile(file.path, function(error, data) {
    // console.log( file.path ) displays what you expect.
    fs.writeFile(/* define new file name */, data, function(error) {
    });
  });
}
```