# How to use the onclick property for a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page which basically has four image thumbnails in the `<ul>` tags. Below is another image area. When you click the thumbnail, the full picture is displayed

```
<body>
<h1>Image Gallery</h1>
<ul>
<li><img class="preview" src="images/blue.jpg" title="blue"></li>
<li><img class="preview" src="images/red.jpg" title="red"></li>
<li><img class="preview" src="images/yellow.jpg" title="yellow"></li>
<li><img class="preview" src="images/green.jpg" title="green"></li>
</ul>
<h2>Picture Description</h2>
<img id="large" src="images/blue.jpg">
</body>
```

JS Code goes here:

```
var preview=document.getElementsByClassName("preview")
var target=document.getElementById("large")
var desc=document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0]
for (var i=0;i<preview.length;i++) {
    function showpic() {
        target.src=preview[i].src
        target.innerHTML=preview[i].title
    }
    preview[i].onclick=showpic
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhantomJS Node - page.open - cannot keep track of multiple pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086360/phantomjs-node-page-open-cannot-keep-track-of-multiple-pages)

Answer (score 1):

You were close! The problem with defining a function in a loop like that is that all of the clicks were triggering the last version of the function. Using `this` avoids that problem as we only have to define `showpic` once.

```
function showpic(){
    var target=document.getElementById("large")
    target.src=this.src
    target.innerHTML=this.title
}

var preview=document.getElementsByClassName("preview")
var desc=document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0]
for (var i=0;i<preview.length;i++) {
    preview[i].onclick=showpic
}
```

**EDIT**
There is something you can also do, it's closer to your programming style I think:

```
var preview=document.getElementsByClassName("preview")
var target=document.getElementById("large")
var desc=document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0]
for (var i=0;i<preview.length;i++)
{
    preview[i].onclick=function(event1){
        target.src=event1.srcElement.src
        target.innerHTML=event1.srcElement.title
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but now working. The console log shows no error message.

Answer (score -1):

```
try this.
var preview=document.getElementsByClassName("preview")
var target=document.getElementById("large")
var desc=document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0]
for (var i=0;i<preview.length;i++)
{
preview[i].onclick=showpic();
}
function showpic(){
target.src=preview[i].src
target.innerHTML=preview[i].title
}
```